# Compile error with boost asio.hpp

Tags: c++, boost

When I include boost/asio.hpp to my source file and compile, I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_complex.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/type_traits.hpp:81,
             from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:21,
             from /usr/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:39,
             from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:20,
             from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:24,
             from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:20,
             from Source.cpp:166:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3.2/include/c++/complex: In function ‘_Tp std::__complex_abs(const std::complex<T>&)’:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3.2/include/c++/complex:558: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

As can be seen, I'm compiling under Suse Linux 2.6.31.14-0.8 with gcc 4.3.2. I tried

1. Line 558 in complex has "... = std::max(abs(__x), abs(__y));". Hence I tried adding #undef max and #undef abs to see if it will help. It did not help
2. I tried conditional inclusion of BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB and it did not help.

Any pointers to fix this issue is appreciated.

Here is the complete function in complex which is giving the error:

```
  // 26.2.7/3 abs(__z):  Returns the magnitude of __z.


template<typename _Tp>
    inline _Tp
    __complex_abs(const complex<_Tp>& __z)
    {
      _Tp __x = __z.real();
      _Tp __y = __z.imag();
      const _Tp __s = std::max(abs(__x), abs(__y));
      if (__s == _Tp())  // well ...
        return __s;
      __x /= __s;
      __y /= __s;
      return __s * sqrt(__x * __x + __y * __y);
    }
```

Comment: What's in place of the `…`? Can you paste the whole thing with a few context lines above and below?

Comment: Please make it a SSCCE. See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.